# My ::after Background image has a 1px top line, on some screens

Tags: css, svg, background

On some devices screens (laptop), I noticed on Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers, there is line above my backgroungd svg image, on my top menu.

It looks fine if i resize the window, for example it looks good on mobile size screen. If i change the backround height seems to be solved but it will occur on other screen sizes.

```
#site-nav::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 99px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-position-y: 2px;
    background-size: 100% 75px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIGlkPSJDVVBJRE9OIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB4PSIwcHgiIHk9IjBweCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDIwMDAgMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZW5hYmxlLWJhY2tncm91bmQ6bmV3IDAgMCAyMDAwIDI1MCIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9InRleHQvY3NzIj4KICAgIC5tYWlue2ZpbGw6IzIyMmYzNTt9CiAgICAuc2Vje2ZpbGw6I2M5ZTZmZjt9CiAgPC9zdHlsZT4KICA8Zz4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGNsYXNzPSJzZWMiIGQ9Ik0wLDEzNi4yYzEwOS43LDE0LjEsMjU5LjcsMjIuNiw0MDMuOCwyMS42YzM0MC4xLDAsNTA4LjItNTcuNiw2MTAuNS04My40QzExMDQuMSw1Ni4zLDEyNTAuNSwwLDE2NTMuNiwwYzEyOSwwLDI0Ny4zLDUuNiwzNDYuNCwxNS4zVjI1MEgwVjE1NC4yeiIvPgogICAgPHBhdGggY2xhc3M9Im1haW4iIGQ9Ik0wLDE1NC4yYzEwOS43LDE0LjEsMjU0LjcsMjIuNiw0MTMuOCwyMi42YzM0Mi4xLDAsNTA4LjItNTcuNiw2MjAuNS04OC40QzExNTEuMSw1Ni4zLDEzMTEuNSwwLDE2NTMuNiwwYzEyOSwwLDI0Ny4zLDUuNiwzNDYuNCwxNS4zVjI1MEgwVjE1NC4yeiIvPgogIDwvZz4KPC9zdmc+);
    transform: scale(-1,-1.4);
}
```

[I add a printscreen of the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1enR.png)

On firefox, it seems to be fine.
I wonder if the top line is not a part of the svg image. Unfortunatelly I am not a svg expert.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing background-position-y from your css. So that the new CSS looks like this.

```
#site-nav::after {
content: '';
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 99px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
background-size: 100% 75px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
transform: scale(-1,-1.4);
}
```

Comment: If i remove the background-position-y: 2px; from my css the issue it will be fixed on laptop screen,  BUT will occur now on the large desktop screen.

Comment: Try managing the same using media queries, styling the element for particular screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your advice as yes, it could be the solution, but I noted I will have to style too many particular screen sizes. That is interesant because the error do not occur on Firefox. I will try to resize the .svg background to cover all the top of the website to avoid that strange horizontal line.

Comment: Sounds good. Upvote my answer if you find it relevant.